# SSLCipherSuite for Internet Explorer 11

Tags: .htaccess, internet-explorer, firefox, ssl

I am adding SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 in .htaccess file and after that my website is opening in Firefox but not opening in internet explorer 11.

Do i need any other combination for SSLCipherSuite to run my website in Internet Explorer 11?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

> SSL cipher suite support on Internet Explorer depends both on the
>   version of IE and on the version of the operating system

https://github.com/client9/sslassert/wiki/IE-Supported-Cipher-Suites

Try either one of the following for IE11:

- ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA
- ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
- ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA
- ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA

Answer (score 0):

Take the guesswork out of the configuration by using a tool such as the **[Mozilla SSL Configuration Generator](https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/)** to check which configuration you should use.

[image]

(as described in this answer)